# CMAKE: How to install the dependencies of a target

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to install an executable using cmake. My real problem here is: how to install the executable and its dependencies.

Here an example:
I want to install one executable that depend on two libraries of my cmake and one 3rdparty (pre-compiled).

```
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME MyExecutable)
file(GLOB_RECURSE ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_SOURCES *.cpp)    
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} MyLibrary1
  MyLibrary2
  ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY})
install(TARGETS ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
 ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
 LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
 COMPONENT ${EXECUTABLE_NAME})
```

At the end I would like to find with this kind of CMakeLists.txt my two libraries, my executable and Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY in the install folder and in my package.

What I have found, but I did not succeed to use:

1. BundleUtilities.cmake, here an example: https://cmake.org/Wiki/BundleUtilitiesExample.
   As you can see it seems to do the perfect jobs, but it's complaining about "external prerequisites". I personally found that normal and I don't understand how to fix that. (Note: it succeeds in finding and copying the dependencies into a same folder before failing, Doc: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/BundleUtilities.html)
2. GetPrerequisites.cmake. get_prerequisites is a lower level function that allow you to get the dependencies. The thing is, I don't any good way/best practice to use it.

Thanks,

Comment: you may find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487506/11107541

Answer (score 0):

I personally would make a library out of all of your dependencies with `add_library(MyLibrary1 STATIC/SHARED/INTERFACE)` and for boost most probably `add_library(boost INTERFACE)` followed  by adding any include directories and linking the `.a`s or `.so`s to them.

I would then link all my dependencies to `MyExecutable` as you have above. And at any point you can call the `install` function on all of these targets one at a time.

If you don't like repeating

```
install(TARGETS target
 ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
 LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
 COMPONENT target
)
```

then you could break it out in to a function, something like this

```
function(INSTALL_CUSTOM target
  install(TARGETS target
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
   LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
   RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
   COMPONENT target
  )
endfunction()
```

and then you could just call `INSTALL_CUSTOM(MyLibrary1)` or `INSTALL_CUSTOM(boost)`.

Comment: Note that as of CMake 3.14, you no longer need that destination boilerplate as long as it matches the 3.14 defaults.