# CMake `INSTALL` for targets and its SO dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

My target linked with several libraries using `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` with `PUBLIC` keyword, The `INSTALL` command looks like `INSTALL(TARGETS foo DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin)`. I want somehow to force the cmake to include all (preferably excluding system libraries) libraries (SOs only) I link with to be included in the installation process. I've tried EXPORT keyword but looks like it affects only libraries which I build with in my project and marked with the same `EXPORT` as `foo` library.

Is it possible?

EDIT001: Additional information that may affect answer.
I'm using [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) to manage third parties. So the `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` looks like

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(foo PUBLIC
                      GTest::GTest
                      GTest::Main
                      ${GOOGLE_MOCK}
                      event
                      ${THRIFT_LIBRARIES}
                      ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                      lzo2
                      sqlite3
                      ${ZeroMQ_LIBRARY}
                      gRPC::grpc
                      gRPC::grpc++
                      xml2
                      stdc++fs
                      bfd
                      -l:libisal.so.2
                      sgutils2
                      pthread
                      uuid
                      rt
                      )
```

So, essentially what I want to achieve is to take all these libraries which are macro'ed by `vcpkg`, like `${THRIFT_LIBRARIES}, ${Boost_LIBRARIES} and gRPC::grpc` and so on

Comment: You need to list everything you need to install separately. AFAIK, CMake doesn't make any analysis which will automagically install all the dependencies. Besides, you have only one target: `foo` and the command install *targets*. Of course, there are other install commands but they aren't close to the `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` command either.

Comment: if there is no other option it sounds good enough, other question is, can I access all dependencies added via `target_link_libraries` as they generated into `make` files, since it already has full path to the SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CMake itself does not allow to install dependencies automatically. This would be a rather hard task, because it would have to consider a lot of corner cases.

Just think of transitive dependencies (I don't know if this is the right word), like: Your `libA` depends on `libB`, which depends on `libC`. How should CMake get this from the CMakeLists, where only `libB` is listed?

Or: What do you consider a *system library*? Everything that is not in `PATH`? How do you know which libraries are installed system-wide on the client's machine?

You see, there are some really tricky things to consider.

Here are some possibilities you have:

- Ask your users to install the dependencies.
- Statically link libraries into your binary.
- Copy library files using [`install(FILES files... DESTINATION <dir>)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-files). Maybe your dependency manager can help creating the list of files.
- Write a script that does something like [`windeployqt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) for Qt-based applications on Windows: Analyze the binary file (e.g. using `ldd myApp`) and automatically copy over the required dependencies.

Comment: you definitely right about corner cases, but your item three nails the point, give me the list of stuff my library linked with and I will pick whatever needed from this list. Unfortunately, I didnt find way to get aforementioned list

Answer (score 7):

As of cmake 3.21, you can now do with:

```
install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS gRPC::grpc)
install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

etc.

See [new Install command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#imported-runtime-artifacts).

Comment: I've tried to do this with spdlog by doing: `install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS spdlog::spdlog)`, however, I get the message: "install IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS given target "spdlog::spdlog" which is not an executable, library, or module." Like the OP I'm using vcpkg and importing spdlog using find_package. Any ideas?

Comment: @anthony-calandra: I'm not familiar with spdlog, but doing an "apt search" on it says that it's a header-only library.  So there shouldn't be any runtime artifacts that you need to install.

Comment: I think they are working on this bug you mentioned @Antony Calandra. https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22406 They didn't anticipate people using it in this fashion when they wrote it. But the users think otherwise. To be short: cmake doesn't know whether the lib is .so or .a.