# How to transitively copy DLLs with cmake and Conan?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, fmt

I have a CMake project where I link with `fmt::fmt` which is specified in the conanfile.py and installed and all cmake config files have been generated by `Conan` and been used by CMake, so far all good. (I use `from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeDeps, CMakeToolchain, CMake`

I try to **copy all transitive dependencies** of my target `tgt` with https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS (I know about conan‘s import feature but I wanted to give it a try with CMake!)

```
add_executable(exe main.c)
target_link_libraries(exe PRIVATE otherTarget fmt::fmt)
add_custom_command(TARGET exe POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:exe> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:exe>
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
  )
```

Strangely, the otherTarget.dll will be copyied to the Exe. But fmt::fmt `dll` is not copied, because something is either wrongly setup in the generated files? Conan however sets IMPORTED_LOCATION to the `.../lib/fmtd.lib` on the referencing targets of `fmt::fmt`, and I suspect CMake does not include it in `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS` because only `.dll` files are treated?

Does anybody know whats going on here?

Comment: "generated by Coban" - typo?

Comment: I'm curious about what the purpose of the copy is. CMake links the source fmt to the exe and not the copy fmt to the exe (right?)... If the purpose is related to installation and bundling dependendcies with an installation, you may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487506/11107541

Comment: Its all about bundling an installation