# Make the OpenCV libraries that the binary program really needs available to the customer

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have installed the `OpenCV` package in `Ubuntu22.04` by `sudo apt-get`.

And the said `OpenCV` is one of the dependencies for my project.

The problem is that the target computer does not have installed `OpenCV` and it's impossible to use `sudo` permission.

How to make the `OpenCV` that I am using portable by the [`install` command of `Cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html)? I intend to copy the `OpenCV` libraries when `make install` is invoked.

What I have tried is seen below.

Here is a portion of the CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

message("OpenCV_LIBS:")
foreach(lib  ${OpenCV_LIBS})
message("${lib}")
endforeach()

install(FILES ${OpenCV_LIBS} TYPE LIB)
```

Here is the output when `cmake ..` is invoked:

```
OpenCV_LIBS:
opencv_calib3d
opencv_core
opencv_dnn
opencv_features2d
opencv_flann
opencv_highgui
//omits some similar output
```

Here is the error message when `make install` is called:

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:130 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find "/home/john/myproject/opencv_calib3d":
  No such file or directory.
```

And ***what's more***, how to only make the libraries that the binary program really needs available to the customer other than sending all the libraries of `OpenCV` to the customer?

Tips: the customer uses the same OS.

Comment: Easy option would be to link with OpenCV statically. | The problem with install is likely that you're giving it just library names, but the actual files are located in some system directory. | Personally, instead of linking with every single OpenCV module and letting the linker sort it out, I prefer to explicitly link only with those modules that I actually need. So drop the `${OpenCV_LIBS}`, and start with `opencv_core` and systematically add libraries based on the functions you've used (or based on complaints of the linker).

Comment: @DanMašek :） Thank you for the reply. It's a solution. But not an automatic one.  ***And*** how to tell the `cmake` to statically link the OpenCV?

Comment: Have you checked [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098134/cmake-install-for-targets-and-its-so-dependencies) on the similar question? It suggests to use `install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev For `grpc`, it's `install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS gRPC::grpc)`. What about `OpenCV`?

Comment: Actually, `opencv_calib3d`, `opencv_core`, and all other elements in `${OpenCV_LIBS}` are IMPORTED **targets** (And that explains why you have failed to install them via `install(FILES)`). Note, that `install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS)` installs only files directly representing by the those targets. If you want to install indirect dependencies too, then you could look into [file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#get-runtime-dependencies) command.