# call `install` on a cmake target that install also dependencies

Tags: windows, installation, cmake

I've a simple `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.22)

project (proj-console)

find_package (Boost COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED QUIET)

include_directories (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../..)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set (PROJECT_SRC
  main.cpp
  Options/Parser.cpp
)

if (WIN32)
  configure_file(Version.rc.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Version.rc @ONLY)
  set (VERSION_SRC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Version.rc
  )
endif ()

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SRC} ${VERSION_SRC})

target_link_libraries (
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  PRIVATE
  proj-mylib1
  proj-mylib2
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)

configure_file(Resources/Config/console.ini ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/Config/console.ini COPYONLY)

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_20)

install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DIR})
install (FILES Resources/Config/console.ini DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DIR}/Config)
```

The project is built correctly, but I've a problem when calling `cmake install`. I've configured it in order to put everything in `${INSTALL_DIR}` that I've defined in my root `CMakeLists.txt` (simply an `export` folder). When I run it cmake only copies the executable and the configuration file, while I want to copy also the dependencies and the libraries that I've found with `find_library` (boost program-options in this case).

For installling boost dependencies, I've added this line (following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098134/cmake-install-for-targets-and-its-so-dependencies)):

```
install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

But I obtain an error:

> 1> [CMake] CMake Error at src/myproj/Console/CMakeLists.txt:38 (install): install IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS given target "optimized" which does not exist.

It does not work with my compiled libraries like `proj-mylib1` (that's a library that I build with cmake in the same project).

I've also used the solution proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884439/how-to-use-cmake-file-get-runtime-dependencies-in-an-install-statement), but with no results; I've added this at the end of my `CMakeLists.txt file` but it copied only two dll (`advapi32.dll` and `aepic.dll`) in another export folder (inside my build folder instead that in the root like I've defined):

```
install(CODE [[
  function(install_library_with_deps LIBRARY)
    file(INSTALL
      DESTINATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
      TYPE SHARED_LIBRARY
      FOLLOW_SYMLINK_CHAIN
      FILES "${LIBRARY}"
    )
    file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES
      LIBRARIES ${LIBRARY}
      RESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR RESOLVED_DEPS
      UNRESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR UNRESOLVED_DEPS
    )
    foreach(FILE ${RESOLVED_DEPS})
      if(NOT IS_SYMLINK ${FILE})
        install_library_with_deps(${FILE})
      endif()
    endforeach()
    foreach(FILE ${UNRESOLVED_DEPS})
      message(STATUS "Unresolved from ${LIBRARY}: ${FILE}")
    endforeach()
  endfunction()
  file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES
    EXECUTABLES  $<TARGET_FILE:proj-console>
    RESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR RESOLVED_DEPS
    UNRESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR UNRESOLVED_DEPS
  )
  foreach(FILE ${RESOLVED_DEPS})
    install_library_with_deps(${FILE})
  endforeach()
  foreach(FILE ${UNRESOLVED_DEPS})
    message(STATUS "Unresolved: ${FILE}")
  endforeach()
]])
```

So what I'm doing wrong? What's the correct way to perform the cmake install command that copies everything in a dedicated folder?

Comment: `install IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS given target "optimized" which does not exist.` - This is because `Boost_LIBRARIES` variable contains like `debug <debug-lib> optimized <release-lib>`. Instead of the variable, use an IMPORTED target which `find_package(Boost)` provides (in your case, `Boost::program_options`). "It does not work with my compiled libraries" - Those libraries could be installed with regular `install(TARGETS)`.